# PHP: get the last row in database using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three rows in a table. I'm trying to get and display the last row of my table and, instead,  its always displaying the result of the middle row.

I have tried to used the `"DESC"` or `"DESC LIMIT 1"` but still its not working.

Example:

I have a 3 rows in my table of `tbldata`.

```
0:5

0:10

0:15
```

The query for this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT fldBldgName, fldTimestamp,   
MIN(fldTotalDuration)fldTotalDuration   
FROM tbldata    
WHERE  fldNetname = '".$network."'   
AND fldBldgName = '".$bldg[$i]."'    
AND  fldWeek = '".$week."'   
AND fldMonth = '".$month."'   
GROUP BY fldBldgName   
ORDER BY  fldBldgName,fldTimestamp, fldTotalDuration DESC");
```

I already tried also the `ID to order` by but still its not working. I tried the `timestamp`, but still its not working.

The result for that query is always the `"0:10"`, the correct output should be `"0:15"`.

But then if I have 2 rows only:

```
0:5

0:10
```

the result is : `0:10` which is correct

And so, I also tried it to manually query it in `phpmyadmin`, but it still does not display the last row.

Comment: try  
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC  
Whats the output?

Comment: @T_01..the result are : 0:15, 0:10, 0:5

Comment: @T_01...yeh ...oh yeah! thanks! but why its working like that? is there a different with your query in my query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have an `id` field with `AUTO_INCREMENT` set.

Then try this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Your use of `MIN(fldTotalDuration)` and `GROUP BY` was totally confusing the result you were after.