# How can i get the last record from database by php

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get the last record from database without using:

```
SELECT * FROM 'myTabe' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What's the problem with this statement?

Comment: if u dont have query than how can u get the data for sorting ? do u have any PHP code, if yes please share..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: get the last row in database using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299405/php-get-the-last-row-in-database-using-mysql)

Comment: if you have an id field with AUTO_INCREMENT set. then It's work

Comment: You can use max(id) to get the last id in a subquery and join it back to the main table.

Answer (score 0):

This code selects LAST INSERTED ROW:

```
SELECT * FROM 'mytable' WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```